# Linebreak problem with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, titlesec

I'm trying to format the section titles in my article to be Large, centered and underlined using `titlesec`. Some of my section titles are quite long so i need them to be in multiple lines. However, I always get an error when adding a newline command in the section title and `titlesec` seems to prevent the automatic linebreak. Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\centering}{}{0em}{\underline{\smash{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Very Long \\ Title}
Text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to smash the title? Also, are you sure you want to underline it? Typographically, this is very bad practice.

Comment: Actually I don't want to underline it, but it is mandatory for this document. I am smashing the title, to get the line higher, crossing the descending letters. However, it also does not work without smashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the `soul` package. It works just as fine as egreg's answer but lets me put the underlining higher than the standard height.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\setul{1.5 pt}{.6 pt}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\centering}{}{0em}{\ul{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Very Long very long very long very long very long very long section Title}
Text text text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `\underline` cannot be broken across lines. You can do it with `ulem`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\centering}{}{0em}{\uline}

\begin{document}
\section{Very Long very long very long very \\ long very long very long Title}
Text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]